# Extracting data from JSON and exporting to CSV using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script that will extract data from **JSON** and fill it in a **CSV file**. I have the part of code that will send my hashes and get a JSON response.

Now I just need to find out how to export the data. Example ["title"] => string(12) "Name", the name would go under column "TITLE" in csv file.

```
public function exportdata() {
    $params['hashes'] = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->fetchCol("SELECT url FROM books WHERE url NOT LIKE ''");
    //zddd($params);
    $base = new Base("http://sitepath");
    $json = $base->makeRequest($params);
    $r = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

Here is how the JSON response looks like

```
 ["status"] => string(7) "success"
  ["message"] => string(0) ""
  ["result"] => array(345) {
    [0] => array(4) {
      ["title"] => string(12) "Name"
      ["managerBookId"] => string(4) "12345"
      ["firstCall"] => array(2) {
        ["date"] => string(10) "2017-07-27"
        ["sent"] => int(3225)
      }
      ["secondCall"] => array(2) {
        ["date"] => string(10) "2017-08-03"
        ["sent"] => string(4) "45678"
      }
    }
    [1] => array(6) {
      ["title"] => string(36) "Name"
      ["managerBookId"] => string(4) "12334"
      ["firstCall"] => array(2) {
        ["date"] => string(10) "2018-05-29"
        ["sent"] => int(2614)
      }
      ["secondCall"] => array(2) {
        ["date"] => string(10) "2018-06-05"
        ["sent"] => int(2461)
      }
      ["thirdCall"] => array(2) {
        ["date"] => string(10) "2018-06-12"
        ["sent"] => int(2294)
      }
      ["fourthCall"] => array(2) {
        ["date"] => string(10) "2018-06-19"
        ["sent"] => string(4) "2207"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Ananth I just want to know how to export the data to csv